# Can I nest variables in Flask templates?

Tags: flask

everyone, i met a problem in Flask.
There is a table in mysql named category, I queried all of them, then passed them to a.html, like this :

```
return render_template('admin_index.html', username=session.get('username'), categories=categories)
```

In admin_index.html, I wanna list all of them, here is my code:

```
var _menus = {
    "menus": [
        {
            "menuid": "1",
            "icon": "icon-sys",
            "menuname": "category",
            "menus": [
                {% for category in categories %}
                    {
                        "menuid": "{{ category.id }}",
                        "menuname":"{{ category.name }}",
                        "icon": "icon-users",
                        "url": "{{url_for('admin.category', id={{category.id}} _external=True) }}"
                    },
                {% endfor %}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

but when i ran this, i got an error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

I tried remove {{ category.id }}, turned out OK, I suspect it's not allowed to nest variables in Flask template, which like this :

```
{{ a is {{ b }} }}
```

Is there any way i can nest it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already inside a jinja expression. So the following code is executed:

```
url_for("admin.category", id={{category.id}} _external=True)
```

Because of the `{` it expects a dictionary hence the error.

To use the value of `category.id` simply omit the curly brackets:

```
url_for("admin.category", id=category.id, _external=True)
```

Also note that you forgot a `,` before "_external".