# Variable inside variable in Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, pelican

### 1. Summary

I can't set use variable inside variable in my Jinja2 example.

Solution must be [**Pelican**](https://blog.getpelican.com/)-compatible.

---

### 2. MCVE

#### 2.1. Expected behavior

```
Any text

    Goddess Kira greatest of all time!

    Goddess Kristina greatest of all time!


Another text

    Goddess Sasha greatest of all time!

    Goddess Katya greatest of all time!
```

#### 2.2. my attempt

- [**Live demo on Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraJinja2loops-duplicatetextinsideloops):

```python
"""Jinja2 nested variables example."""
from jinja2 import Template

KIRA_BLOCK = """
{% set first_list = ['Kira', 'Kristina'] %}
Any text
{% for name in first_list %}
    Goddess {{name}} greatest of all time!
{% endfor %}
{% set second_list = ['Sasha', 'Katya'] %}
Another text
{% for name in second_list %}
    Goddess {{name}} greatest of all time!
{% endfor %}
"""

print(Template(KIRA_BLOCK).render())
```

#### 2.3. Problem

I have duplicate `Goddess` and `greatest of all time!` in loops. Can I don't use duplicates?

---

### 3. Not helped

#### 3.1. Similar questions

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32024636/5951529), [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331888/5951529), [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14254308/5951529) and [**many others**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Cot.png) Stack Overflow questions.

#### 3.2. Nested variables

For example, this code doesn't work:

```python
"""Jinja2 nested variables example."""
from jinja2 import Template

KIRA_BLOCK = """
{% set she_greatest = 'Goddess' {{name}} 'greatest of all time!' %}
{% set first_list = ['Kira', 'Kristina'] %}
Any text
{% for name in first_list %}
    {{she_greatest}}
{% endfor %}
{% set second_list = ['Sasha', 'Katya'] %}
Another text
{% for name in second_list %}
    {{she_greatest}}
{% endfor %}
"""

print(Template(KIRA_BLOCK).render())
```

I get traceback:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KiraJinja2.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(Template(KIRA_BLOCK).render())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 945, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 880, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 2, in template
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 901, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 888, in subparse
    self.stream.expect('block_end')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py", line 384, in expect
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'
```

---

### 4. Real example

For preventing [**XY Problem**](http://xyproblem.info/) I post truncated real code:

#### 4.1. Expected behavior

```python
<div class="KiraCategory">First</div>

    <a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, 'https://Alpha.com');" class="Foo">Alpha</a>

    <a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, 'https://Bravo.ru');" class="Bar">Beta</a>


<div class="KiraCategory">Second</div>

    <a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, 'https://Charlie.net');" class="Baz">Gamma</a>
```

The example shows where static is and where variables.

#### 4.2. my attempt

- [**Live demo on Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraJinja2loops-duplicatetextinsideloopsreal):

```python
"""Jinja2 nested variables example."""
from jinja2 import Template

KIRA_BLOCK = """
{% set first_list = [
    ('https://Alpha.com', 'Foo', 'Alpha'),
    ('https://Bravo.ru', 'Bar', 'Beta')
] %}
<div class="KiraCategory">First</div>
{% for url, color, sitename in first_list %}
    <a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, '{{url}}');" class="{{color}}">{{sitename}}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% set second_list = [
    ('https://Charlie.net', 'Baz', 'Gamma'),
] %}
<div class="KiraCategory">Second</div>
{% for url, color, sitename in second_list %}
    <a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, '{{url}}');" class="{{color}}">{{sitename}}</a>
{% endfor %}
"""

print(Template(KIRA_BLOCK).render())
```

Duplicates in my attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [Jinja *macros*](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros); functions that produce output when called:

```html
{% macro she_greatest(name) -%}
    Goddess {{name}} greatest of all time!
{%- endmacro %}

{% set first_list = ['Kira', 'Kristina'] %}
Any text
{% for name in first_list %}
    {{ she_greatest(name) }}
{% endfor %}
{% set second_list = ['Sasha', 'Katya'] %}
Another text
{% for name in second_list %}
    {{ she_greatest(name) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> demo = '''
... {% macro she_greatest(name) -%}
...     Goddess {{name}} greatest of all time!
... {%- endmacro %}
...
... {% set first_list = ['Kira', 'Kristina'] %}
... Any text
... {% for name in first_list %}
...     {{ she_greatest(name) }}
... {% endfor %}
... {% set second_list = ['Sasha', 'Katya'] %}
... Another text
... {% for name in second_list %}
...     {{ she_greatest(name) }}
... {% endfor %}
... '''
>>> print(Template(demo).render())




Any text

    Goddess Kira greatest of all time!

    Goddess Kristina greatest of all time!


Another text

    Goddess Sasha greatest of all time!

    Goddess Katya greatest of all time!
```

or, applying this to your real-life example:

```html
{% macro kira_function_link(url, color, sitename) -%}
<a onclick="KiraFunction(document.all.sitename.value, '{{url}}');" class="{{color}}">{{sitename}}</a>
{%- endmacro %}

{% set first_list = [
    ('https://Alpha.com', 'Foo', 'Alpha'),
    ('https://Bravo.ru', 'Bar', 'Beta')
] %}
<div class="KiraCategory">First</div>
{% for url, color, sitename in first_list %}
    {{ kira_function_link(url, color, sitename) }}
{% endfor %}
{% set second_list = [
    ('https://Charlie.net', 'Baz', 'Gamma'),
] %}
<div class="KiraCategory">Second</div>
{% for url, color, sitename in second_list %}
    {{ kira_function_link(url, color, sitename) }}
{% endfor %}
```